# How to rotate points without moving them?

Tags: java, c++, opengl, math, directx

I need to rotate a triangle so that it lies on a plane given by a normal n and a constant d.
[image]

I have the normal n1 of the plane that the two triangles lie in. Now i need to rotate the right red triangle so that it results in the orange one.
The points of the triangles and the normals are stored as 3-dimensional vectors.
Until now, I did the following:

- Get the normalized rotation quaternion (rotQuat) between n1 and n2.
- Multiply every point of the triangle by the quaternion. Therefore I convert the point to a quaternion(point.x, point.y, point.z, 0) and do the multiplcation as follows: resultQuat = rotQuat * point * conjugate(rotQuat). I then apply x, y and z of the result to the point.

This is how i get the rotation between two vectors:

```
public static Quaternion getRotationBetweenTwoVector3f(Vector3f vec1, Vector3f vec2)
{
    Vector3f cross = Vector3f.cross(vec1, vec2);
    float w = (float) (java.lang.Math.sqrt(java.lang.Math.pow(vec1.getLength(), 2) * java.lang.Math.pow(vec2.getLength(), 2)) + Vector3f.dot(vec1, vec2));
    Quaternion returnQuat = new Quaternion(cross.x, cross.y, cross.z, w);
    returnQuat.normalize();
    return returnQuat;
}
```

The problem is that the triangle has the correct orientation after the rotation, but the triangle also moves it's position. I need a rotation that rotates the triangle so that it's still connected to the two points of the left red triangle (like the orange one). 
How is this possible?

Comment: Just perform a simple translation afterwards? That is basically what any motion consist of: rotation+translation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that rotation matrix/quaternions rotate points around an axis that passes through the origin. To rotate around different point than the origin, you need to translate the triangle points to the origin (just Substract the rotation point value from the triangle points), then multiply by the quaternion and then translate back.

So the algorithm becomes:

- translatedPoints[i] = triPoints[i] - rotationPoint;
- translatedPoints rotate using quaternion
- translate translatedPoints back by adding the rotation point value.

Comment: I think you can skip a translation step if you do this smart.

Comment: @Bernhard Can you explain it further?

Comment: So, if i understood it correctly, I have to take one of the 2 points that the triangles share as my rotation point? I tried this but it messed up the rotated points. The rotationPoint is just the point that the axis which I rotate around goes through, right?

Comment: @concept3d Well, you need one rotation to align normals. After that, one translation should suffice to align origins.

Comment: @Bernhard you still need the extra translation I mentioned to do the actual rotation around your custom rotation point.

Comment: @user3067395 The rotation matrix/quaternion rotates around the origin by default. In order to change the origin point, we perform a transflation to alighn the rotation point with the origin then translate back.

Comment: But what would the rotation point be in the case of my sketch i posted in the question?

Comment: @user3067395  assuming you have all the triangle points, let's assume the triangle base points are t1,t2 and the head point is t3; the rotation point should be `(t1+t2)*0.5`